# Save a sentence with a new line and echo it with new line PHP

Tags: php, forms, textarea

How do I make my website like this :

Wanted to:

I have a  `textarea` in a `form` when I use a sentence like this for example

**Hey I typed this in first line**

**And this is new line**

And I save it to `database` and `echo` it, it goes like this:

**Hey I typed this in first line And this is new line**

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You need to actually attempt something first. SO is for specific problems, not for general "how do write my entire project"

Comment: I am sorry, thank you for your kind advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you display it you also have to transform the `\n` into `</br>`. Use `nl2br()` for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Just additional I will just use this when `echoing` right ?

Comment: Yes, `echo nl2br($your_string);`

Answer (score 0):

Your should just replace char break-line to html tag br

You can use this code before put this value to db.

```
$string = str_replace('\n', '<br>', $string);
```